# webBrowser.Url вывод с запозданием

Tags: c#, webbrowser

При активации формы объекту label1 должно присваиваться след выражение:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Вы сейчас на " + webBrowser1.Url;
    }
```

Однако эта вещь работает с запозданием на один шаг. То есть выдаёт мне предыдущий адрес. Почему?

Comment: Почему-то первоначальное значение webBrowser.Url==null , хотя я вписал в конструкторе Url.

Comment: А он обновляет URL'ы или один раз показал ссылку и больше не показывает? Если только один раз, то может это следует поместить в таймер?

Comment: Да обновляет. Но показывает адреса предыдущих страниц.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот официальный пример кода из msdn:

```
// Updates the URL in TextBoxAddress upon navigation.
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender,
    WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripTextBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
}
```

Вы сделали верно, скорее всего проблему нужно искать в другом месте...
Скорее всего данное событие вызывается раньше чем браузер успел перейти на нужную страницу

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Сидел над этой проблемой весь день.